# Appcelerator IOS Module Development

Tags: ios, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am pretty stuck trying to create a IOS module for Titanium/Appc i am trying to intergrate https://github.com/antiguab/BAFluidView so i can use it in titanium.

I have followed the module tutorials have it working fine with just the standard view but when i try to add BAFluidView it doesnt work.

I have included the classes in xcode and have the code below.

```
#import "ComExampleFluidView.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"
#import "BAFluidView.h"
#import "UIColor+ColorWithHex.h"

@implementation ComExampleFluidView
- (void)initializeState
{
    // Creates and keeps a reference to the view upon initialization
    square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame]];

    BAFluidView *view = [[BAFluidView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame];
    [view fillTo:@1.0];
    view.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0x397ebe];
    [view startAnimation];
    [square addSubview:view];

    [self addSubview:square];
    [super initializeState];
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    // Deallocates the view
    RELEASE_TO_NIL(square);
    [super dealloc];
}
-(void)frameSizeChanged:(CGRect)frame bounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    // Sets the size and position of the view
    [TiUtils setView:square positionRect:bounds];
}
-(void)setColor_:(id)color
{
    // Assigns the view's background color
    square.backgroundColor = [[TiUtils colorValue:color] _color];
}
@end
```

header file is

```
#import "TiUIView.h"
@interface ComExampleFluidView: TiUIView {
    UIView *square;
}
@end
```

Can anyone give some suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

since you are trying to bridge a native view, you need some layout helpers that are required to handle the Titanium-layout-system properly. Please check modules like [ti.googlemaps](https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.googlemaps), especially the [initialization](https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.googlemaps/blob/master/ios/Classes/TiGooglemapsMapView.m#L23) of views. In addition, your custom setters like `setColor` need to apply the color to your `BAFluidView`, not to your `UIView`, so you need to keep a reference of that inside your header. I guess the ti.googlemaps example should explain all concepts you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: hi Hans thanks for the advice ill take a look and check back ;)

Comment: Hey there, did you have success?

Comment: Hi Hans, unfortunately not still trying to get this to work, stuck when trying to bridge a native view. I can’t find any information tutorials or something to point me in the right direction just trying to mimic parts of the googlemap code into my project then testing. So am i even going about the right way should i be trying to apply this to a titanium view or is there a better way you could suggest? Or are there any resources you can suggest?

Comment: OK..you know what? I took your library and created the core of the module for you: https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.fluidview. Example included!